# aws codecommit pr approval got overwritten

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I nnoticed that aws codecommit behave in a "weird" way

1. I create a PR off a branch
2. Team members approved the PR
3. I push some code into that branch
4. Approval count resets back to 0

Is there a setting to prevent the approval count from resetting back to 0 when a commit is pushed? It also doesn't help that the Activity tab doesn't actually tracked what has happened (ex. PR was approved by someone before)

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not currently support this. Please see below communication from AWS after I raised a support issue requesting if there is the capability to disable the overriding of approval rules when there is a new push.

> *"Unfortunately there is no such setting, this is not a bug but a design choice behind the approval rules."*

The only workaround is to disassociate the approval rules from the repository.